# Assigning variable value to id of an input element in javascript/ jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to assign variable value to dynamically created input elements. But I couldn't. The input elemts are created but not with id.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

// Declaring global variables   

    var cnt = 1;
    var fooId = "foo";
    var cnt1 ='aaaa';


// Code for Changing the datalist for second input testingphase when ever first input Tasks has been changed.


        $("#tasks" + cnt).change(function () {
        $("#activitytype" + cnt).replaceWith('<input id="activitytype" + ctn value="asasa" name="ActivityType" placeholder="ActivityType" >');

        if (bla1 == 'Service Request') {
            $("#testingphase" + cnt).replaceWith('<input id="testingphase" + ctn list="Service Request" name="Tasks" placeholder="Tasks2">');
        //  changingactivity ();


             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your `replaceWith` method slightly to include the variable without quotes. Change:

```
 $("#activitytype" + cnt).replaceWith('<input id="activitytype" + ctn value="asasa" name="ActivityType" placeholder="ActivityType" >');
```

To something like:

```
 $("#activitytype" + cnt).replaceWith('<input id="activitytype' + ctn + '" value="asasa" name="ActivityType" placeholder="ActivityType" >');
```

Comment: Thanks dude. Its works out. I've been rolling y head for 2 hours for this.. Thanks

Comment: Can we able to add div element inside a form dynamically? If so, then I also need to add input elements created dynamically inside that div elements.

Comment: Can you tell me how does id="activitytype' + ctn + '" this works.. the single quotes.